# How to unpack values from a list stored inside another list

Tags: python, list, unpack

I have a list containing some elements, a lit and some other elements like so `[a, b, [c, d, e], f, g]` and I would like to get `[a, b, c, d, e, f, g]`. I tried using itertools which I'm not familiar with, but I was unsucessfull:

```
from itertools import chain

a = 1
b = 2
c = [3, 4, 5]
d = 6
e = 7

list(chain(a, b, c, d, e))
```

It throws a TypeError

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: it is not very clear what your input is and what output you expect

Comment: The code you posted is quite different from what your description says you're trying to do.  There's only one list in the posted code, and it contains no sub-lists.

Comment: anything else except `c` is not iterable and thus cannot be passed to `itertools.chain()`. Right now this is XY problem. What do you try to achieve exactly? Probably `[a, b, *c, d, e]`, but really depends on the bigger picture

Comment: What is the ```*``` for in front of ```c``` ? I would like to unpack every element of the list ```c``` in the outer list. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

you could convert from a list mixed of lists and ints to a list strictly of lists, and then apply itertools chain.

```
from itertools import chain

l1= [1,2,[3,4,5],6,7]
l2 = list(chain.from_iterable(i if isinstance(i, list) else [i] for i in l1))
```

Or check the type and then extend or append the new list;

```
l1= [1,2,[3,4,5],6,7]    
l2 = []
for i in l1:
    l2.extend(i) if isinstance(i, list) else l2.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function that takes an arbitrary number of arguments, you could use the below solution

First I convert all input arguments to lists `arg if isinstance(arg, list) else [arg]`, and then I use a "trick" with the summation function to flatten the lists.

```py
def unpacker(*args):
    return sum([arg if isinstance(arg, list) else [arg] for arg in args], [])
```

Example

```py
a = 1
b = 2
c = [3, 4, 5]
d = 6
e = 7

print(unpacker(a, b, c, d, e))
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```